# UItextView in UITableview, autocorrection bubble not visible

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uitextview

I have a UITableView with custom cells. The cells containing one UITextView each and the cell is resizing during user type text in the TextView.   My problem is when user is on first row in a TextView autocorrection bubbles wont be visible in the current cell.  Is there any workaround or can someone point me to another direction?

[alt text http://img340.imageshack.us/img340/5414/skrmavbild20100519kl092.png](http://img340.imageshack.us/img340/5414/skrmavbild20100519kl092.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the cell is resizing as the user types, you could set the minimum height of the edited cell to have enough height for the bubbles.  Always measure the active cell as if there were at least two lines.

Each `UIView` has a `clipsToBounds` property that controls wether contents can be drawn outside the bounds.  You might be able to set this to `NO` for all views in the hierarchy between the bubble and cell.  This could have other side effects though.

Also, make sure the active cell has a higher Z order than neighboring cells.  It could simply be that the next cell down is drawing over the bubble, as opposed to the active cell cropping the bubble.

Comment: The thing is that im override UITextView -(UIEdgeInsets) contentInset {return UIEdgeInsetsZero; }, cus I dont want to have this autoscroll on UITextView when begin editing, this is causing that the bubble dosnt "fit"

Answer (score 0):

I propose you a "workaround"

Your user try to edit a row in your table view
-> You present a modal view with a UITextView with dismiss and ok button.